# Промисы в Jquery ( помогите понять принцип )

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Как сделать, что бы обещание срабатывало при выполнении всего содержимого first();
Если добавить в массив сразу AJAX запрос, то всё работает как требуется. Но если first(), то ответа от AJAX  не дожидается, что и логично.

```js
const arr = [];
function first (i) {
  $.ajax({
    url: `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${i}`,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      i: i
    },
    complete: function() {
      console.log('AJAX №' + i);
    }
  })
};

for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  arr.push( 
    first(i)
  );
}

Promise.all(arr)
  .then(resolve => {
    console.log('После AJAX');
  })
  .catch(reject => {

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function first (i) {
  return $.ajax({ ...
```

Comment: Быстро))) Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

`complete` срабатывает после "отработки" всех остальных функций ajax.
Т.е и после события, которое перехватывает `then` в Promise.all()
Может быть не самый элегантный способ - обернуть вызов ajax в еще один Promise.

```js
const arr = [];
function first (i) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
      url: `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${i}`,
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        i: i
      },
      complete: function(data) {
        console.log('AJAX №' + i);
        resolve(data);
      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
};

for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  arr.push( 
    first(i)
  );
}

Promise.all(arr)
  .then(resolve => {
    console.log('После AJAX');
  })
  .catch(reject => {

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```